# CSS :not selector does not neglect the next selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a style to apply when the tag above a `<p>` is not of a certain class, e.g.:

```
:not(.someclass) + p {
    color: yellow
}
```

This works for cases like:

```
<h3 class="someclass">title</h3>
<p>This does not have the style applied</p>
<p>This has the style applied</p>
```

What troubles me is when there is no tag above a `<p>`, I want the style to be applied but it doesn't, e.g.:

```
<p>This should have the style applied but it doesn't</p>
```

How would you fix the CSS to cover both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector can fail only if the paragraph has no previous siblings and this means that it must be the first-child, so modify your rule like so:

```
:not(.someclass) + p,
p:first-child {
    color: yellow
}
```

```css
:not(.someclass) + p,
p:first-child {
    color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="someclass">title</h3>
  <p>This does not have the style applied</p>
  <p>This has the style applied</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This should have the style applied but it doesn't</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Was thinking if the `:not()` selector can affect the `+` selector somehow, but looks like I need this two parts CSS to solve it.

Comment: you need to read the selector from the right: you're targeting a paragraph which must be the next sibling of something which is not .someclass

Comment: yes I know, but I was reading it like a `<p>` not followed by something with class someclass